dialogflow CX v3 java library SessionsClient.detectIntend method: significant delays (over 3s)
Each time SessionsClient.detectIntent in the Dialogflow CX v3 library is executed, it encounters significant delays (over 3 seconds).
After creating a SessionsClient and configuring it to maintain sessions for 24 hours, I attempted to save the generated sessionsClient object itself or convert it to JSON and store it in Redis for reuse, but failedto do so.
Is there a way to store or reuse a SessionsClient created in a Java environment?
Alternatively, if there's a method to reduce the latency to within 1 second, I'd appreciate it.
